Randomising within for each element zone
I have a plugin to generate plants, and I'm trying to use the "For Each Element" zone to generate a collection. I want to add random values to the plant generator so each plant in the collection is unique, but I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this. Ultimately I want to use the collection with "Instance on Points".

The index on "For each element" seems to be constant within the loop and I am unsure how to convert info from element into a usable integer.
I followed a suggestion from another post (How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?) where the "Repeat" zone is used. However, I don't have any seed options on the input.
Edit for clarity: The goal here is to distribute points randomly on a grid node. I'm using noise to to change the density in "distribute points on faces"

I think you should elaborate more on your "goal", because "index" is a usable integer. Your custom node group is not connected to anything, and probably "geometry to instance" is creating a single instance.

Even though I don't know your goal, I believe "geometry to instance" must be "inside" the loop, and you should "join" the generated instance to an accumulated geometry inside the loop

@DanielMöller this was absolutely the answer. Once I put "geometry to instance" and "join geometry" inside the loop it all worked out. Much appreciated!
